# Validating `DefaultAzureCredential()` using Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, exception

What are some example methods for logging and handling exceptions using try/except and `DefaultAzureCredential()`?

**Example:**

When `DefaultAzureCredential()` is used in a Python Azure Function, it generates a few `WARNING` messages and one of the `.get_token` methods in the credential chain succeeds.

**I want to log which one succeeded and which ones failed.**

```
WARNING:azure.identity._internal.decorators:EnvironmentCredential.get_token failed: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.

WARNING:azure.identity._internal.decorators:ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.

WARNING:azure.identity._internal.decorators:SharedTokenCacheCredential.get_token failed: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.

WARNING:azure.identity._internal.decorators:VisualStudioCodeCredential.get_token failed: Failed to get Azure user details from Visual Studio Code.
```

And then it just succeeds, but there is no message indicating which one succeeded. In this case, running snippets in a `.ipynb` file in VS Code).

**How do I log and handle errors when using `DefaultAzureCredential()` in production?**

Looking for an example of something like:

```
try:
    credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
    logging.info(f'<whichever>.get_token succeeded')
except Error1 as e1:
    logging.error(f'EnvironmentCredential.get_token failed: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.', e1)
except Error2 as e2:
    logging.error(f'ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.', e2)
...<etc>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways I might approach this but none are particularly pretty.  At the risk of a naive suggestion, if you want a fine-grained understanding of what worked in sequence, you could take an approach similar to what your example sketched out using the components credentials listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet):

```py
for credential in [EnvironmentCredential, ManagedIdentityCredential, ...]:
  try:
    credentials = credential()
    # Validate credential functionality...
    logging.info('{}.get_token succeeded'.format(credential))
  except Error1 as e1:
    logging.error('{} failed due to {}'.format(credential, e1))
```

I suggest this because it does not seem like what you want is exposed in an easily accessible manner, looking at the `ChainedCredential` source [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/7a730caaeb6ca118a95b86df08448b2aac9713ae/sdk/identity/azure-identity/azure/identity/_credentials/chained.py#L67) (history is built up but only used in the log message).

More "self-contained" approaches might involve creating a custom wrapper that basically does what `ChainedCredential` does for `DefaultAzureCredential` in running the list of get_token calls, but with more ability to export the success history, you could likely hack that off of the code I linked in [2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/7a730caaeb6ca118a95b86df08448b2aac9713ae/sdk/identity/azure-identity/azure/identity/_credentials/chained.py#L67) and do something directly comparable to [the DefaultAzureCredential logic](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/7a730caaeb6ca118a95b86df08448b2aac9713ae/sdk/identity/azure-identity/azure/identity/_credentials/default.py), but at the end of the day it's all isomorphisms of the sample above.

Don't hesitate to shout if I've misunderstood some aspect of the question or your requirements/constraints; and as always feel free to reach out if you need to get in touch with us [on our github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) (full disclosure, am a maintainer for some of the other Python Azure SDKs)

Comment: Thank you for providing some ideas. I want to make sure I'm not overriding anything that `DefaultAzureCredential()` is doing and am actually *using* `DefaultAzureCredential()`. I don't see it listed in your proposed solution. Where is the actual call to `DefaultAzureCredential()` in your solution?

Comment: To be clear, my solution basically "works around' needing to consume `DefaultAzureCredential()` explicitly, because I do not see an obvious way to extract the information you need from it; it simply does not persist it, so you'd need to have "your own version" of `DefaultAzureCredential()` which is what I outline above.

Echoing myself to be VERY predantic: I do not see a way that you CAN actually use `DefaultAzureCredential` explicitly with the requirements you have above (to know what succeeded and failed within it)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Due to my current level of experience, I'd prefer not to create my own version of `DefaultAzureCredential`. I'll pursue an alternative unless you know a simple Python method to catch all the "Warning" messages that are displayed.

Answer (score 8):

Just to supplement the accepted answer with some more details, let me add that `DefaultAzureCredential` does log this information. For example, if you enable INFO-level logging:

```
import logging
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

logger = logging.getLogger('azure.identity')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s %(name)s] %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

You'll see log messages like these from `DefaultAzureCredential`:

```
[INFO] DefaultAzureCredential - EnvironmentCredential is unavailable
[INFO] DefaultAzureCredential - ManagedIdentityCredential is unavailable
[INFO] DefaultAzureCredential - SharedTokenCacheCredential is unavailable
[INFO] DefaultAzureCredential acquired a token from VisualStudioCodeCredential
```

You'll see the failed attempts logged only the first time the `DefaultAzureCredential` instance acquires a token. Once one of its constituent credentials provides a token, it uses that credential exclusively. So this particular `DefaultAzureCredential` will always authenticate through Visual Studio Code, and in the logs you'll see this message whenever it does so:

```
[INFO] DefaultAzureCredential acquired a token from VisualStudioCodeCredential
```